# 18650 12P2S Charging with BMS and Charge Control Module

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, batteries

I have a quick question on charging options for a 12S2P 18650 Li-Ion pack made of Samsung INR18650-35E cells. I have a pack built using a 12S balancing charging BMS (https://www.ebay.com/itm/233763643368). The design I'm building is already using a Mean Well MW LRS-350-48 48V 7.5A 350W Regulated Switching Power Supply for powering some other components. I would ideally like to use the Mean Well to also charge the battery pack if possible. I understand that charging the pack directly isn't really an option, but is it possible to put something like this:

[https://www.amazon.com/Acxico-XH-M604-Battery-Protection-Overcharge/dp/B081YQ5YPF/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=XH-M604&qid=1622670586&s=electronics&sr=1-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081YQ5YPF))

I would wire this between the Mean Well PSU and the BMS? Obviously it has the low/high voltage limits, but is that going to provide good solution to maximize the longevity of the cells and the capacity? I'd just rather save the use of an additional power supply if possible. On a side note, the speed of charge really isn't a concern for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add CC limiter and adjust CV to 52V then add a current sense to cutoff at CC/10, so no.

Or leave at 48V add a PTC to avoid overloading the  Meanwell then cutoff when it reaches 48V for longer life but slightly reduced capacity with 2V hysteresis.

Use a 50mV full scale current sense and comparator is an option to latch off charging at 50 mA.